# Implementing vine like video recording in android?

Tags: android, video-recording, vine

I have implemented the video recorder with touch to start recording . But the process fails when it tries to record small videos of milliseconds . The app works fine but is not smooth as vine. Is there any third party api for video recorder that could work for me . Thanks ..

Answer (score 1):

Vine uses a combination of JavaCV and FFMPEG. If you have a rooted device you will be able to find the ".so" files inside data/data/ folder.